# Android: how to force ScrollView layout, and then scroll to a point?

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a ScrollView which I'm adding a number of custom Views to.  After adding the custom Views, I would like to be able to Scroll to a particular one.  But, immediately after adding the custom views, the ScrollView hasn't been resized, so I can not scroll.  Any idea how I can force this resize?

```
for(int i = 0, i < numberOfViews, i++)
{
  scrollView.addView(new MyView(...));
}

//tried this, doesn't seem to be helpful 
scrollView.requestLayout();

//at this point scrollView dimensions are 0,0,0,0 
scrollView.scrollTo(5, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do, but I wanted to scroll all the way down, and couldn't just do that: I had to do it like this:

```
((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.yourId)).post(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.yourId)).fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
         }
 });
```

It will update later, so your view is made :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this.  Even if I use the post(...) method, the ScrollView height is still 0 when the fullScroll(...) method executes (I can tell by debugging, and placing a breakpoint in the fullScroll(...) method).

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution is to plan the scroll and do it on the next onLayout(). Example code here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10209457/1310343