# How to make ScrollView aware of changes in its child's size?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I've been wanting to create a `ScrollView` that could adapt its current scroll position in respect to changes in its child's size. So that if my user has scrolled, say, 75% of the child's height at a time, they will still be at 75% of the child's updated height when it increases/decreases.

To do this, obviously my `ScrollView` needs to know when its child size is being updated. This seems like a trivial task at first, but unfortunately every method I tried so far has yield no result:

- Using an `OnLayoutChangeListener`
- Overriding `onLayout()`
- Overriding `onSizeChanged()`
- Overriding `onScrollChanged()`

All of them reports size changes of the `ScrollView` itself; not its child. This information is useless for me because my `ScrollView` is not supposed to change sizes.

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

---

***p.s.***, I understand that [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993179/android-notify-scrollview-that-its-childs-size-has-changed-how) might looks similar to mine. But my case demands no intervention of components other than the `ScrollView` itself, while the question above needs the `ScrollView` to be notified by an outside entity (presumably an `Activity`).

Comment: see [this](http://pastebin.com/qd2TvFsM)

Comment: I got the general idea.. But if you want to add it into that snippet then please do. Also, you might consider turning this comment into an answer so that I could mark it as accepted.